# How to NIntegrate $(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac1x\right\rfloor}/x$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

*Mathematica* fails with

```
Integrate[(-1)^Floor[1/x]/x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

How can I evaluate it?

In view of it, I unsuccessfully try

```
NIntegrate[(-1)^Floor[1/x]/x, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 20 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {6.08983877753243723225686862226814152545986400616302122725995044034*10^-325}. NIntegrate obtained 710.5859812076798`and 3.956615692341655` for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 710.586

This question is inspired by [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/nintegrate-extremely-piecewised-functions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Mathematica* needs to be helped a bit for this problem, as neither `Integrate[]` nor `NIntegrate[]` are sufficiently smart enough.

We proceed as in a hand calculation: letting $n\in\mathbb N$, we consider the integral

$$\int_{\frac1{n+1}}^{\frac1n}\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor}}{x}\mathrm dx$$ and then sum up all the terms.

*Mathematica* is still unable to deal with this integral, but evaluating it for increasing $n$ reveals a pattern:

```
Table[Integrate[(-1)^Floor[1/x]/x, {x, 1/(n + 1), 1/n}], {n, 8}]
   {-Log[2], Log[3/2], -Log[4/3], Log[5/4], -Log[6/5], Log[7/6], -Log[8/7], Log[9/8]}
```

and we find that the general term is $(-1)^n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$. (I tried to use `FindSequenceFunction[]` on this sequence, but it took too long and I lost patience.)

A plausibility check:

```
Block[{$MaxPiecewiseCases = 120, n = 100}, 
      Integrate[(-1)^Floor[1/x]/x, {x, 1/(n + 1), 1}] == 
      Sum[(-1)^k Log[1 + 1/k], {k, n}] // Simplify]
   True
```

and the OP's integral is thus equivalent to evaluating

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$

which `Sum[]` is unable to do, but is easily dealt with by `NSum[]`:

```
NSum[(-1)^k Log[1 + 1/k], {k, 1, ∞}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 40]
   -0.451582705289454864726195229894882608267
```

---

If you really must use `NIntegrate[]`, one could generate the sequence of integrals

$$\int_{\frac1n}^1\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor}}{x}\mathrm dx$$

and accelerate the convergence rate of the sequence using the Wynn $\varepsilon$ algorithm, via [`` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834) (`SequenceLimit[]` in earlier versions):

```
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[Table[
              NIntegrate[(-1)^Floor[1/x]/x, {x, 1/n, 1},
                         Method -> {"SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision",
                                    "MaxPiecewiseCases" -> (n + 2)},
                         WorkingPrecision -> 50], {n, 2, 30}]]
   -0.45158270528945486472619524
```

Note the use of [`"SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#440163298) to ensure the splitting of the integral into intervals where a polynomial approximation will be fine, and `"MaxPiecewiseCases"` will ensure that the whole business is split up.

---

Mariusz's answer shows how to get a closed form answer. Here's one way to do it in *Mathematica*.

First, note the following:

```
{D[(-1)^(n - 1)/(n + 1)^z, z], D[(-1)^n/n^z, z]} /. z -> 0
   {(-1)^n Log[1 + n], (-1)^(1 + n) Log[n]}
```

Thus,

```
Sum[D[(-1)^(n - 1)/(n + 1)^z, z], {n, 1, ∞}] +
Sum[D[(-1)^n/n^z, z], {n, 1, ∞}] /. z -> 0 // FullSimplify
   Log[2/π]
```

Comment: +1. Nice, but rather by hand with help of Mathematica. The question remains open: how to NIntegrate that?

Comment: FindSequenceFunction fails with it in short time.

Comment: Now I accept it.

Answer (score 10):

The OP's integral is thus equivalent to evaluating the sum:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \ln
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Using  identity:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(1-\exp (-t)) \exp (-n t)}{t} \, dt=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
puting to sum:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n ((1-\exp (-t)) \exp (-n t))}{t}=-\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t+e^t t}$$
and integrating:

$$\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t+e^t t} \, dt=\ln \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)$$
**Closed form solution:**
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor }}{x} \, dx=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \ln
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)}$$

**EDITED:**

Solution by: `Maple 2018`

[image]

---

**Alternative how find closed form solution ?:**
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } -(-1)^n \ln (n)+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \ln
   (n+1)$$
By `Regularization Sums`

```
 Sum[-(-1)^n*Log[n], {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Abel"] + 
 Sum[(-1)^n*Log[n + 1], {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Abel"] // FullSimplify

 (* Log[2/π] *)
```

---

**A Feynman's trick:**

```
s1 = Sum[-(-1)^n*n^k, {n, 1, Infinity}] + 
Sum[(-1)^n*(n + 1)^k, {n, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify

Limit[D[s1, k], k -> 0] // FullSimplify

(* Log[2/π] *)
```

Comment: Neat idea to use Frullani's integral. (IOU one upvote.)

Comment: @J.M.Analytic solution is always the best solution no need  to struggling with `NSum` or `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk what is the role of $k$ in the sum of your closed form solution?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas. A typo.Corrected.Thanks.`:)`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, impressed how you obtained the closed-form (+1)

Answer (score 4):

This is the same calculation from another point of view. We can realise that after the variable change $t=1/x$, the integrand is equal to:

$$\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor }}{t}$$

and integrated in $(1,\infty)$. After plotting the function:

[image]

we can calculate easily the integrals and, summing them:

```
NSum[Evaluate@Integrate[(-1)^Floor[n]*1/t, {t, n, n + 1}], {n, 1, ∞},
     Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]

(* -0.451583 *)
```

or integrating piecewisely in $(n,n+1)$, with $n\in \mathrm{N}$:

```
Assuming[n > 1 && n ∈ Integers, 
Integrate[(-1)^Floor[n]*t^-1, {t, n, n + 1}]]
```

$$(-1)^{ n } \log \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)$$

and summing:

```
NSum[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/n], {n, 1, ∞}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]

(* -0.451583 *)
```

---

By using the Frullani's integral identity proposed by @MariuszIwaniuk:

$$\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} dx=(f(0)-f(\infty)) \log \frac{b}{a}$$

his closed form is obtained:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor }}{x} \, dx=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)$$

where $\log$ is the natural logarithm in this case.

Comment: When you changed variables, did you remember to differentiate your substitution?

Comment: @J.M., yes, I found my error. Good catch ! thnx...

Answer (score 4):

```
 Sum[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

returns unevaluated, but the following product gives a closed form

```
 Log[Product[(1 + 1/(2*k)) / (1 + 1/(2*k - 1)), {k, 1, Infinity}]]

 (* Log[2/Pi] *)

 N[%, 40]

 (* -0.4515827052894548647261952298948821435718 *)
```

Comment: How come this `Product`,Can you explain ?

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: If n is even then (-1)^n*Log[1 + 1/n] = Log[1 + 1/n]. If n is odd then (-1)^n*Log[1 + 1/n] = -Log[1 + 1/n] = Log[1/(1 + 1/n)]. And Log[a] + Log[b] + Log[c] + ... = Log[a*b*c*...]. It's clear now ?

Comment: Yes it's clear. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more automized

```
Block[{x, n},
  NSum[
     (-1)^n Evaluate[ Integrate[1/x, {x, 1/(n + 1), 1/n}, Assumptions -> n > 0]], 
     {n, 1, ∞}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.806038, -0.451583}

Comment: No output during several minutes in version 11.3 on Windows 10. Did you check your suggestion?

Comment: @user, it works quickly in 11.2; what version are you using?

Comment: Works, but does not result.

Comment: I use version 11.3 on macos and it returns ``-0.4515827052894538` `` after a second or so. Have you tried to clean the kernel? If `x` or `n` have values assigned to them then `Evaluate` might do shabby things.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thank you for your advice. Now it works well.